# Не работает скрипт, который записывает данные с формы в Гугл таблицу

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, fetch

По непонятной причине не срабатывает скрипт записи в Гугл таблицу.
Причем с этим же кодом работает 2 других проекта и работают прекрасно.

Пытался по всякому и копировал код и копировал таблицу с Apps scripts, но безуспешно, запись не происходит и возвращает ошибку.

Код отправки на стороне пользователя и Гугла ниже

```
let form = document.getElementById("myform");
let message = document.getElementById("message");
let timer;


form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let formData = new FormData(form);
    let url = 'здесь ссылка на скрипт из Google Apps script';

    let response = fetch(url, {
        method:'POST',
        body: formData
    });
    response.then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
    }).then(function(result) {
        if (result.result == 'success') {
            form.reset();
            showMessage('Данные успешно отправлены', 'green');
        } else {
            form.reset();
            showMessage('Произошла ошибка: ' + result.error, 'red');
        }
    });
});


//Код скрипта на стороне гугл таблицы:
var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup () {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

Comment: Мы возможно сами можем придумать ошибку и ее рещить. однако хочется увидеть вашу ошибку, которая происходит именно у вас

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @SwaD возвращается эта ошибка {
    "result": "error",
    "error": {
        "name": "Exception"
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился путем написания функции doGet, которая проверяет наличие параметров запроса и в случае успеха запускается функция doPost. Но что интересно еще 2 таблицы сделанные несколько месяцев назад работают вполне успешно без функции doGet.